# Gazebo installation in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: gazebo, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to install Gazebo on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I am facing the below problem

```
admin@admin:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-simulator-gazebo
[sudo] password for admin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-simulator-gazebo
```

Is there any problem with the code I am executing? or is it the problem of Ubuntu version?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158811/gazebo-installation-in-ubuntu-14.04-lts/) by [Raghu Parvatha](https://answers.ros.org/users/15256/raghu-parvatha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-04-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-25**:
You can check if any package is available with `apt-cache search ros-indigo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`simulator_gazebo` is no longer a ROS package as of Hydro, so also not in Indigo:

http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#Gazebo

You probably want the `ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs` package. A list of all Indigo packages, filter on gazebo in their name, can be found here:

http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=gazebo

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0